# How to get the length and height from a h265 rtsp frames

Tags: height, width, resolution, hevc

Not able to get the frame width and height from the rtsp url from h265 camera. Can I get any guidelines for fetching the resolution.

Comment: Please add some context. Are you using some kind of webcam? If not `rtsp url from h265 camera` would not make any sense. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Usually, there is no frame resolution within the rtsp url. So you need to access/play the stream to get to that info.

Comment: Actually it was from h265 Bitstream which contains the information of video. i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can process the sps packets to find the height and width for your bit-stream Follow the **Sequence parameter set RBSP** semantics in the following link and move the bytes to process the sps data LINK: [ITU H265 DOC](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiFgIv797fyAhWdgtgFHVZbAm4QjBAwAXoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itu.int%2Frec%2Fdologin_pub.asp%3Flang%3De%26id%3DT-REC-H.265-201911-I!!PDF-E%26type%3Ditems&usg=AOvVaw2IurAJPMbPOm7V0LGAa1ec)